# не переводит в переменную

Tags: c++, xcode

```
using namespace std; int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        //встреча номер 5
        //задание 2
        // вводит с клавиатуры время начала и время завершения телефонного 
        // разговора (часы, минуты и секунды). Посчитать стоимость
        // разговора, если стоимость минуты – 30 копеек.
        const double min=0.30;
        cout<<"polzovatel vvodit nachalo razgovora:"<<endl; 

        float start;cin>>start;
        cout<<"vvedite conec razgovora:"<<endl;
        double endTime;cin>>endTime;
        if(endTime>=start){  
          int res=(endTime-start)*min;
          cout<<"vremia razgovora:"<<res;
        }
        else
            cout<<"vvedeno ne correctnoe znachenie";
        return 0;

    }
```

подскажите пожалуйста у меня в переменной int res не приводит к целому значению

Comment: а к чему приводит?

Comment: *"часы, минуты и секунды"* - соответственно надо прочитать 6 значений и перевести время в минуты

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что у вас "в переменной int res не приводит к целому значению"???